# React js child component not rendered when props changed

Tags: reactjs, ajax, render, react-state

react noob here.
I have this component where I'm showing list of pokemons gotten from API calls.
I have this dropbox which would change the `region` state to be one selected, and fetch list of data (pokemons) based on the region thru API.
`number` props passed to `PokeCard` child component is the corresponding pokemon number I would fetch within the component.

The problem that I am facing is that after I first change region, I would get correct data list, but changing the region after that would not render wanted list(the list from first changed region would persist), although I am passing correct `number` as props (I checked it using `console.log` within `PokeCard` component). I do not know how react renders component deeply(nor proper "practice"), so I am wondering if the react does not execute `renderedPokemonList` part after first. If it is not being executed, how should I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

```js
handleChangeRegion = (SelectedRegion) => {
    let pokedexNum = 0;
    switch(SelectedRegion) {
        case "National":
            this.setState({
                region: "National",
            })
            pokedexNum = 1;
            break;
        case "Kanto":
            this.setState({
                region: "Kanto",
            })
            pokedexNum = 2;
            break;
        case "Johto":
            this.setState({
                region: "Johto",
            })
            pokedexNum = 3;
            break;
        case "Hoenn":
            this.setState({
                region: "Hoenn",
            })
            pokedexNum = 4;
            break;
        case "Sinnoh":
            this.setState({
                region: "Sinnoh",
            })
            pokedexNum = 5;
            break;
        case "Unova":
            this.setState({
                region: "Unova",
            })
            pokedexNum = 9;
            break;
        case "Central Kalos":
            this.setState({
                region: "Central Kalos",
            })
            pokedexNum = 12;
            break;
        case "Coastal Kalos":
            this.setState({
                region: "Coastal Kalos",
            })
            pokedexNum = 13;
            break;
        case "Mountain Kalos":
            this.setState({
                region: "Mountain Kalos",
            })
            pokedexNum = 14;
            break;
        case "Alola":
            this.setState({
                region: "Alola",
            })
            pokedexNum = 21;
            break;
        default:
            this.setState({
                region: "National",
            })
            pokedexNum = 1;
            break;
    }
    let url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/" + String(pokedexNum) + "/"
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data) {
                this.setState({pokemons: data.pokemon_entries}, () => {})
            }
        })
        .catch(console.log)
}

render() {
  const renderedPokemonList = this.state.pokemons.map((pokemon, idx) => {
    return (
      <div key={pokemon.entry_number}>
        <div>
          <PokeCard number={pokemon.pokemon_species.url.slice(42, -1)}></PokeCard>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <Container>
      <div>
        <ButtonDropdown>
          <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropDownOpen} toggle={this.toggle} >
            <DropdownToggle color="primary" caret>
              {this.state.region}
            </DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeRegion("National")} dropdownvalue="National">National</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeRegion("Kanto")} dropdownvalue="Kanto">Kanto</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeRegion("Johto")} dropdownvalue="Johto">Johto</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeRegion("Hoenn")} dropdownvalue="Hoenn">Hoenn</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeRegion("Sinnoh")} dropdownvalue="Sinnoh">Sinnoh</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeRegion("Unova")} dropdownvalue="Unova">Unova</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeRegion("Central Kalos")} dropdownvalue="Central Kalos">Central Kalos</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeRegion("Coastal Kalos")} dropdownvalue="Coastal Kalos">Coastal Kalos</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeRegion("Mountain Kalos")} dropdownvalue="Mountain Kalos">Mountain Kalos</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeRegion("Alola")} dropdownvalue="Alola">Alola</DropdownItem>
            </DropdownMenu>
          </Dropdown>
        </ButtonDropdown>
      </div>
      <div>
        {renderedPokemonList}
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

+++ actually after some debugging(`console.log`ing the passed props in PokeCard child component), I have found that when changing the region, it would not modify first region's data but fill up the additional data. For example, when I first select region Kanto(containing 151 entries), `state.pokemons` would get filled up with array of 151 Kanto pokemons, and then when changing region to Alola(containing 403 entries), the `state.pokemons` would keep first 151 Kanto's pokemons and the rest will be filled with Alola's pokemon. I'm not understanding how this happens...

Comment: Show the `this.handleChangeRegion` event handler.

Comment: Are you using the [PokéAPI](https://pokeapi.co/)? It actually returns `id`s for each pokemon. You should not try to slice it from the `url`.

Comment: @goto1 added `handleChangeRegion` function!
@trxn I'm fetching data from pokeAPI's pokedex, which only gets `name` and `url` of each pokemon by pokedex region. I have added `handleChangeRegion` as well.

Comment: @Jaebi when you `console.log(this.state.pokemons)` in the `render` method, do you see the updated state/array after you make the next selection?

Comment: @goto1 yes. after making the next selection, console.log(this.state.pokemons) gives the correct state/array (of changed region), but the list rendered is still the first region's data no matter how many times I change the region +++ I have added additional findings in the original post

Comment: Could you recreate this example in something like `CodeSandbox.io`? Everything appears just fine...

Comment: @goto1 of course. I have recreated (without styling) this example thru `CodeSandbox.io`. Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-river-gd3ty?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js). You could see the same problem mentioned at the end of the original post.

Comment: @Jaebi I am not sure if I am seeing the behavior you're explaining in your edit. For example, if I click on `Kanto` and do `console.log(this.state.pokemons.length)` in the `render` method, I get `151`, and then when I click on `Alola`, I get `403`, which appears to be correct. The list also gets re-render correctly, but you're making **a lot** of `HTTP` request, making things slow, so I'd probably rethink that a little bit.